# Why i get error like can't connect to server in ec2

Tags: jenkins

I am unable to connect to remote ec2 host and added credentials in jenkins server using manage jenkins->configure system, during test connection. I always get error as can't connect to server.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whether you can really connect to the EC2 instance from the Jenkins server?

Comment: Yes,i am able to ssh successful from jenkins server which is inside docker.Still the issue persist when i tried to connect from jenkins console and i created one test job to check got error as following below [SSH] Exception:Auth fail com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail